# Run code on a timer even when app closes bind with ui thread? - Android

Tags: android, service, timer, android-asynctask, android-handler

I am working on this part of an app where the user is supposed to press a button and then a timer shows up in a ListView. When the timer goes to 0, a method needs to be called. However, if the timer is pressed, the method call is cancelled. This is simple enough right, but the kicker is, the timer countdown and method call need to happen even if the app isnt running. the user can press the button again to add another timer to the listview and have its own proccess.

Ive used AsyncTasks a lot in previous apps and feel like this wouldn't be useful in this situation because to my knowledge the lifecycle of the asynctask is as long as the activity.

Ive looked into handlers and services but haven't really implemented them before, Im not really sure which would be better to handle this.

Im looking for the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

in Actviity.onDestroy include asynchTask.cancel(true). It will trigger InterruptedException which you can catch in AsyncTask doInBackground, so that if the task has been interrupted you don't call the method.

Another way (less efficient and therefore less recommended): before calling the method check if(actvity.isFinishing())

Comment: Thanks for the answer @cyanide but doesn't the async task follow the same lifecycle as the app, so the action would only be done if the user has the app open? I'm trying to make it so the action will be done regardless... Ive done some more research and think that the service is the right way to go and Ill just run a new thread from within the service everytime a new timer is created, then i will have the main activity listen to the srvice with a broadcast reciever that way the user can close the app and come back in to it and still get the timer update and the code can still go off.